# В чем различие инициализации richedit

Tags: c++, winapi

Появился вопрос, чем отличаются такие инициализации richedit:

```
//1)
LoadLibrary(TEXT("Riched32.dll")); 
HWND rConsoleField = CreateWindow(RICHEDIT_CLASS, "", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 10, 370,
    480, 100, window, NULL, instance, 0);
//2)
LoadLibrary(TEXT("Msftedit.dll"));
HWND g_hRichEdit = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
    "RICHEDIT50W","My Rich Edit", WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_MULTILINE, 2, 2,   200, 300, window, 0, instance, NULL);
```

Я так понимаю в первом варианте автоматически определяется тип richedit, а еще есть в чем разница?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, автоматического определения тут нет. Первый вариант создает RichEdit версии 1.0, второй - версии 4.1. Определение RICHEDIT_CLASS разворачивается в `"RICHEDIT"` или `"RichEdit20W"`, в зависимости от версии Windows SDK, однако реальная версия RichEdit определяется загружаемой DLL. Подробнее см. [Versions of Rich Edit](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/about-rich-edit-controls#versions-of-rich-edit)

Кроме того, во втором случае для RichEdit задаются [стили](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/constants) WS_BORDER и WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, которые включают отображение объемной рамки вокруг элемента управления, и ES_MULTILINE, который делает его многострочным.

Comment: а какой вариант в каких ситуациях применять? Я так понимаю второй более современный, следовательно его

Comment: @helldrg Да, если нет каких-то особых причин, например поддержка старых ОС, лучше использовать более новый.